# Unhandled Exception: NoSuchMethodError: Class 'FirebaseAuthException' has no instance getter '_message'

Tags: flutter, firebase, dart

Help me pls.
I have this error.
10Q

Unhandled Exception: NoSuchMethodError: Class 'FirebaseAuthException' has no instance getter '_message'.
E/flutter ( 5700): Receiver: Instance of 'FirebaseAuthException'
E/flutter ( 5700): Tried calling: _message

```
await _auth
    .signInWithEmailAndPassword(
  email: _emailTextEditingController.text.trim(),
  password: _passwordTextEditingController.text.trim(),
)
    .then((authUser) {
  setState(() {
    firebaseUser = authUser.user;
  });
}).catchError((error) {
  showDialog(
      context: context,
      builder: (c) { 
        return ErrorAlertDialog(
          message: error._message == '[firebase_auth/user-not-found] There is no user record corresponding to this identifier. The user may have been deleted.'
            ? 'Email or password incorrect' : 'Error',
        );
      }); 
});
```

```
error._message == '[firebase_auth/user-not-found] There is no user record corresponding to this identifier. The user may have been deleted.'
            ? 'Email or password incorrect' : 'Error',
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You are being told that there is no getter named _message for FirebaseAuthException. If you go to the code for that class, or the documentation ([here](https://firebase.google.com/docs/reference/android/com/google/firebase/auth/FirebaseAuthException)) and look at the methods you have available to you,
_message is not one.

There is one there (getErrorCode) that you should be able to compare with much easier.

Comment: OK. Then how do I get this String `'firebase_auth/user-not-found'` in this String `'[firebase_auth/user-not-found] There is no user record corresponding to this identifier. The user may have been deleted.'`

Comment: I'm not 100% sure but I believe the error code you are looking for is just "user-not-found". You should determine what that is and then error.getErrorCode() == that.

Comment: this doesn't work for me either. I have get this error. `NoSuchMethodError: Class 'FirebaseAuthException' has no instance method 'getErrorCode'.
E/flutter ( 8385): Receiver: Instance of 'FirebaseAuthException'
E/flutter ( 8385): Tried calling: getErrorCode().`

Comment: I found this code. It seems to work fine. `String myString = error.toString().split(' ').first; myString == [firebase_auth/user-not-found]`

Answer (score 0):

I think that the _message was called on null, I am not sure about this.